# java.lang.IllegalAccessError when creating Avro objects from own functions in MapReduce

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, avro

I have a Hadoop MapReduce program that in a self created function in the Map phase, uses Avro to store data before sending it to the reduce phase. When I am running the function, I get this error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method org.apache.avro.specific.SpecificData.<init>()V from class com.example.myapp.avro.PointList
```

The PointList data type has `int`s, but it did not have trouble with `double`s. Do you know what is causing this?

Answer (score 2):

Quoting the JavaDocs for [`IllegalAccessError`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/IllegalAccessError.html):

> Thrown if an application attempts to access or modify a field, or to call a method that it does not have access to.
>   Normally, this error is caught by the compiler; this error can only occur at run time if the definition of a class has incompatibly changed.

It is highly likely that the MapReduce job was developed and compiled against one version of Avro and then after deployment into the Hadoop cluster, it began using a different, incompatible version of Avro at runtime.  I recommend reviewing the runtime classpath to see if it is picking up a different version of Avro than what you expected.